# How can find wordpress admin screen option inside the wp-admin folder

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, admin

I am not using any plugin i want to make bootstrap admin dashboard on word press admin.

1. how i can change Word press welcome message ?
2. how i can change word press screen option ?

Comment: Please tell me where i can find the files inside wp-admin folder. what are the file name for wordpress screen name. i am not looking for frontend option.

Comment: Editing question, not comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the welcome panel off, incidentally resulting in the removal of the welcome message, by doing the following:

Locate the file: `/wp-admin/index.php`

Just before wp_dashboard() is called, add the following line:

`<?php remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' ); ?>`

This will also remove the corresponding screen option.

As far as changing the text from "*Welcome Text*" to "*Some Other Welcome Message*", this is not set in any php file. You will need to have access to the MySql database. You will likely find the welcome text in the wp_options table. A simple SQL query will help you to find the exact location.

**References:**

Welcome Panel:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/welcome_panel

Database Diagram:
https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/2a/WP3.9.4-ERD.png